# Map User data in resource section

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm experimenting with AWS cloudformation. For this template, I'm trying to link user data is linked with the parameter `selectAMI`. If `AmazonLinux2` is selected, script will install `httpd`. If `UbuntuServer` is selected, script will install `apache2`.

So, obliviously scripts for both is different. I tried to implement this with conditions please refer the `YAML script` below.

```
---
Mappings :
  mapAMI :
    AmazonLinux2 :
      AMI : ami-090fa75af13c156b4

    UbuntuServer :
      AMI : ami-052efd3df9dad4825

  mapUserData :
    AmazonLinux2 : 
      Data : |
        #!/bin/bash -xe
        sudo yum update -y
        sudo yum install httpd
        sudo systemctl start httpd
        sudo systemctl enable httpd.service
        echo "User Data executed successfully and installed HTTPD" > AmazonLinux2.txt

    UbuntuServer :
      Data : |
        sudo #!/bin/bash -xe
        sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
        sudo apt install apache2
        sudo systemctl start apache2
        sudo systemctl enable apache2.service
        echo "User Data executed successfully and installed apache2" > UbuntuServer.txt

Parameters :
  selectAMI :
    Description : Select the operating system or machine image for the instance. Amazon linux 2 or Ubuntu
    AllowedValues : 
      - AmazonLinux2
      - UbuntuServer
    Type : String

Conditions : 
  IsAmiUbuntu : 
    !Equals [!Ref selectAMI, UbuntuServer]

Resources : 
  EC2Instance : 
    Type : AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      UserData :
        Fn::Base64 :
          Fn::Sub :
            !If [IsAmiUbuntu, !FindInMap [mapUserData, UbuntuServer, Data], !FindInMap [mapUserData, AmazonLinux2, Data]]
...
```

When I try to validate the template, I'm facing with `ValidationError - Template error: One or more Fn::Sub intrinsic functions don't specify expected arguments. Specify a string as first argument, and an optional second argument to specify a mapping of values to replace in the string`.

Please help me out regarding how can we map userdata properly so that, `httpd` or `apache2` are installed upon creation of `EC2Instance`

Comment: Just get rid of the Fn::Sub

Comment: @Paolo I have tried it. stack was created BUT userdata is not executed (.txt file not created). Please checkout my full code <https://github.com/jballipalli/InfrastructureAsCode/blob/main/AWS/EC2withhttpd.yaml> `main` branch - No Sub; `test` branch - with sub. please check it out and help me pass the userdata

Comment: Your template looks fine. If that text file isn't created that means the script errored out earlier. Try running the script manually in an instance

Comment: @Paolo finally learned new things and resolved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fellow programmers/enthusiasts,

Thanks to @Paolo.

Below are the few problems I have faced and the solution to the problem.

1. why is userdata NOT executing?

It turns out the `-y` flag was missing in the userdata. So, the execution came to a halt as it is waiting for user input indefinitely. Below is the updated mapping section snippet from the code. Even though HTTPD or Apache2 were installed, the `.txt` files from the last line were not created or they are created in different locations.

```
Mappings :
  mapAMI :
    AmazonLinux2 :
      AMI : ami-090fa75af13c156b4

    UbuntuServer :
      AMI : ami-052efd3df9dad4825

  mapUserData :
    AmazonLinux2 : 
      Data : |
        #!/bin/bash
        sudo yum update -y
        sudo yum install -y httpd
        sudo systemctl start httpd
        sudo systemctl enable httpd.service
        echo "User Data executed successfully and installed HTTPD" > ~/AmazonLinux2.txt
    UbuntuServer :
      Data : |
        #!/bin/bash
        sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
        sudo apt install -y apache2
        sudo systemctl start apache2
        sudo systemctl enable apache2.service
        echo "User Data executed successfully and installed apache2" > ~/UbuntuServer.txt
```

2. How to map userdata in the resource section?

We need to remember that we are not replacing any variable. So `Fn::Sub` is completely unnecessary. Since we are using two functions to map (Fn::Base64 & Fn::If), One of the function must be full form and other can be short form. Check the note section in [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-base64.html).

Here is the code snippet for implementation.

```
Conditions : 
  AmIUbuntu : 
    !Equals [!Ref selectAMI, UbuntuServer]

Resources : 
  EC2Instance : 
    Type : AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      UserData :
        Fn::Base64 :
          !If [AmIUbuntu, !FindInMap [mapUserData, UbuntuServer, Data], !FindInMap [mapUserData, AmazonLinux2, Data]]
```

3. What else did I learn?

Check the log files. when userdata executes, AWS logs it. Executed correctly no problem, else check the `cloud-init-output.log` file and decode and resolve the issue.

Run the below command to `cat` the log file.

`sudo cat /var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

When using AmazonLinux2, YUM is accessing amazon's yum repository with HTTPS protocol. So, make sure to provide an `outbound HTTPS` rule in your security group.

Allow the `inbound SSH` rule to set up EC2 instance connect. EC2 instance connect also works with ubuntu not only amazon linux.

Checkout the template [validator](https://www.cloudformation-validator.com/). Use with Caution!

Interested to check my full code? [Click here](https://github.com/jballipalli/InfrastructureAsCode/blob/main/AWS/EC2withhttpd.yaml)